# keep private google indoor locations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, indoor-positioning-system

Once again, I'm trying to deal with something not really well documented on Google Maps API.

I'm doing a small webapp which would require to be able to map indoor areas BUT I've to keep them private.

For now, I don't find any informations related to this question.
I've found many quite similar questions on stackoverflow which seems to feet my needs regarding the title, BUT once I read the question, everything is related to Android or IOS however, I'm looking to do this on a regular WebPlatform using Maps APIs provided for this plateform.

If anyone as a hint, it will really help so, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to actually get the current position of your user, or do you simply want to display the map?

Comment: I want to be able to add custom indoor map on Google Map but keep them private. I've seen a lot of videos on YouTube about indoor mapping, and I think that I'll use the GroundOverlay class of GMaps APIs in the end. It seems to fit my request perfectly and had the advantage of using additional overlay from my servers on the Js client side.

Comment: @DrI did you solve your issue? how do you handle it? I'm having the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for custom  StreetViews you find on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomStreetView

Keeping the images  private is not hard to achieve, the images are loaded directly by the client, so you may e.g. use a serverside script that handles the requests and for example checks for a valid session before it delivers the images.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it will be useful but indeed, I'm rather looking for the map indoor layers over maps 2d view ;-) I know that it's pretty simple to have this feature using android and iOS SDK but on my project it's all about web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the GoogleMaps community forum (https://support.google.com/maps/thread/124604237/how-can-i-make-indoor-maps-private?hl=en) it is not possible to render google indoor maps private. One solution could be using mapspeople api which uses google maps and draws indoor maps on a top layer, or resort to mapwize which utilizes OpenStreetMaps as a base map to draw indoor maps layers on.
https://www.mapspeople.com/mapsindoors/
https://www.mapwize.io/
note that mapspeople requires payment, while mapwize has a very basic free version.

Comment: Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.